# Am I updating the React state correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React state, I have the state:

```
this.state = {
  users: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "john",
    age: 27
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "ed",
    age: 18
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "mel",
    age: 20
  }]
}
```

I am rendering the `name` correctly. When you click on the name, it should remove the name, which will need an `onClick` that takes in a function and that returns a `removeUser` function.

It is my understanding that you do not want to mutate the state in React, but return a new state. So, in my `removeUser` function, I did:

```
removeUser(index) {
  // Making a new copy of the array
  const users = [...this.state.people].splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({ users });
}
```

I `bind` my method with `this.removeUser = this.removeUser.bind(this).`

When I tested out my code, I am removing the users as expected. However, when I run my code against a test that my friend wrote, I got a failed test that said: `Expected 1 to be 0`

That message tells me that I must be mutating the state somehow, but I am not sure how. Am I returning a new array and updating the state correctly? Can someone explain to me how I should update my state correctly in this case?

Here is the full code:

```
class Group extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        {id: 1, name: "john", age: 27}, 
        {id: 2, name: "ed", age: 18}, 
        {id: 3, name: "mel", age: 20}
      ]
    }

    this.removeUser = this.removeUser.bind(this);
  }

  removeUser(index) {
    const users = [...this.state.users].splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ users });
  }

  render() {
    const list = this.state.users.map((user, i) => {
      return (
        <div onClick={() => this.removeUser(i)} key={i}>{user.name}</div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.splice()` is not a pure function. So it modifies the state as soon as you call you it. You should not use that method with React. Watch this video - https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread

Comment: @TJBlackman, it's not a problem to splice a new array. The problem is that `users` doesn't contain the spliced array, it actually contains the removed node.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the reason to NOT use `splice()`..... :|

Comment: @tjblackman, no. `splice` and `sort` edit in-place which means you should **be careful** if you use them. It doesn't mean "never used them". Instantiating a new array instance and then operating on that instance is perfectly fine with react.

Answer (score 2):

```
const users = [...this.state.users].splice(index, 1)
```

looks like it should be removing an item from a collection, which I suppose it technically is. The problem is that `users` doesn't contain the list of users you want to keep.

Instead, `splice` has modified your new array in-place and then returned the removed items:

[`splice` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> ### Return value
>
> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

Instead, if you'd like to use `splice`, create a new array:

```
const users = [...this.state.users]
```

and *then* splice the new array:

```
users.splice(index, 1)
```

---

You'll run into a similar issue if you need to [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) an array.

The issue of modifying data in-place is generally frowned upon for [react](/questions/tagged/react), in favor of immutable references. This is because React uses a lot of direct comparison of objects as a heuristic approach to speed things up. If your function modifies an existing object instance, React will assume the objects haven't changed.

The act of copying to a new object and *then* operating on the data comes with some tradeoffs. For removing a single item, it's negligible. For removing *many* items, you may be better served by an alternative method, such as multiple slice calls:

```
const users = [
  ...this.state.users.slice(0, index)
  ...this.state.users.slice(index + 1)
]
```

However this too is quite verbose.

Another approach is to use an immutable variant of splice:

```
// this quick example doesn't handle negative start indices
const splice = (start, deleteCount, ...items) => arr => {
  const output = []
  let i
  for (i = 0; i < start && i < arr.length; i++) {
    output.push(arr[i])
  }
  output.push(...items)
  for (i += deleteCount; i < arr.length; i++) {
    output.push(arr[i])
  }
  return output
}

const users = splice(index, 1)(this.state.users)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also change your onClick and pass it the `user.id` instead of the index.  that would allow you to filter the results instead of needing to splice the array.

`onClick={() => this.removeUser(user.id)}`

```
removeUser(id) {
  const users = this.state.users.filter((user) => user.id !== id);
  this.setState({ users });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `slice()` instead of `splice()` because `splice()` mutates the original array, but `slice()` returns a new array. `Slice()` is a pure function. Pure is better!!

```
removeUser(index) {
    const users = [
    ...this.state.users.slice(0, index),
    ...this.state.users.slice(index+1)
    ];
    this.setState({ users });
  }
```

[Here is JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmmt9efw/)

Comment: I have to protest this being down-voted. The question was "Am I updating the React state correctly" and a fundamental principal of React is to produce new data, not modify existing data. I understand that you can create a copy of the state, and mutate that new array, but that's unnecessary data-duplication. It's redundant, and it doesn't adhere to React methodology very well at all.